# Is there an easter egg in the credits of Robocop?

Tags: robocop, robocop-1987

I heard that there was an in joke in the credits of Robocop. Is that true?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, in the closing credits:

[image: PROSECUTION BY ENFORCEMENT DROIDS]

The final paragraph states:

> THIS MOTION PICTURE IS PROTECTED UNDER THE LAWS OF THE UNITED STATES AND OTHER COUNTRIES AND ITS UNAUTHORIZED DUPLICATION, DISTRIBUTION OR EXHIBITION MAY RESULT IN CIVIL LIABILITY AND CRIMINAL PROSECUTION **BY ENFORCEMENT DROIDS**

*"Enforcement droids"* is clear reference to the [ED-209](http://robocop.wikia.com/wiki/Enforcement_Droid_Series_209).